# Reutilizar variaveis de função

Tags: python

Tenho um *script* em Python dividido em funções e preciso acessar uma variável de uma função em outra função exemplo:

```
import glob, os, time, datetime, sys, platform
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

os.chdir = 'C:\Zabbix\Temp'

#Pegar SO e retorna os valores de acordo com a plataforma: 0 - Linux; 1 - Windows; 2 - ERROR
def getOperationSystem():
    OpSys = platform.system()
    print(OpSys)
    if OpSys == 'Windows':
        return(getParameters('C:\\Zabbix\\Parameters.txt'))
    elif OpSys == 'Linux':
        return('#')
    else:
        print('Sistema Operacional desconhecido')
        return(2)
        StopIteration()

#Pegar os parametros no arquivo Parameters
def getParameters(dirBkp):
    with open(dirBkp, "r") as arq:
        for linha in arq:
            global values
            values = linha.split(';')
            return getTasks(values[2])

#Valida se o processo do backup está em execução: 0 - Sim; 1 - Não
def getTasks(name):
    read_process = os.popen('tasklist /v').read().strip().split('\n')
    for i in range(len(read_process)):
        process = read_process[i]
        if name in read_process[i]:
            return 0
            StopIteration    
    getTimeArq(values)

#Valor tempo do ultimo arquivo
def getTimeArq(values):

    bkp_name = values[2]
    print("Nome do Bkp:\t\t\t", bkp_name)
    bkp_name = bkp_name+"*.log"
    print(bkp_name)

    log = glob.glob(bkp_name)
    log.sort(key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)  

    print (log[0])
```

No caso, o `getParameters`, possui uma variável que deverá ser usada em 3 ou mais funções de 20 (que há no *script*)

Ela carrega diversos valores onde cada função puxa um valor, ao tentar usa-la no `getTimeArq` ele me retornou isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pela mensagem, você tentou chamar a função `getTimeArq` sem indicar os parâmetros. Para chamar uma função, você precisa colocar os parenteses e, neste caso, o valor de `values`. Algo como `x = getTimeArq(meus_values)`.

Comment: Mesmo usando o método que tu recomendoou, agora ele me da o retorno none... como se estivesse vazio =/

Comment: Você poderia postar o 'erro' ou a saída de forma completa ?

Comment: Claro, pra ficar mais fácil vou dar um edit postanto todo o código e o print da saida OK?

Comment: Eu tenho um outro script que funciona (poŕem ele foi elaborado para receber os parametros vindos da linha de comando e é lago que não pode mais ocorrer então coloquei todos os parametros dentro de um txt que a variavel value está recebendo e printando os valores conforme preciso porém ao passar para a Variavel LOG ela fica nula

Comment: Cara resolvi hsuahsuhauhsauhsaus Vlw pela ajuda eu que fiz merda e não tinha visto vou editar com a resposta

Comment: Nesse caso , responda seu próprio post com a sua resposta. Da forma mais elaborada possível. Assim quem encontrar de alguma forma a pergunta pode ter uma ideia do que tu fez para resolver

Comment: Caro Wallace, use o campo de resposta para adicionar a resposta. Faça o tour para entender como o site funciona https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Crie um objeto fora da função e passe ele como argumento.

Ex.:

```
#!/bin/python3
class fake_global_variables(object):
    nome = ''

def get_dados(memory):
    memory.nome = input('Nome :')
    return ('Que nome legal.')

fake = fake_global_variables()
get_dados(fake)
print(fake.nome)
```